# How to shrink the space between the title and the top of the given page

Tags: spacing, chapters

[image]

This image describe my question: I want to shorten the distance between title and top of the page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{thesis}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\centering\Large\bfseries}{\filcenter{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{\chaptertitlename}}\@Chapter\  \thechapter}}{16pt}{\Large}
\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

    \parindent=0in
    \parskip=5pt
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
%   \cfoot{\thepage}


    \chapter*{\large{Abstract}}


\end{document}
```

Comment: We have no idea what you have done. Please provide a short document (an MWE) from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}` that shows your problem and that we can compile.

Comment: Just add the command \vspace{-50pt} or whatever before the title. If that does not work, please provide a complete MWE (minimal working example).

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{thesis}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\normalfont\centering\Large\bfseries}{\filcenter{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{\chaptertitlename}}@Chapter\ \thechapter}}{16pt}{\Large} \begin{document} \frontmatter \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\parindent=0in
\parskip=5pt
\pagestyle{plain}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
% \cfoot{\thepage}

\chapter*{\large{Abstract}}
\end{document}